# Self-Signed SSL certificate for local IP

Tags: ssl, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

Development certificate created by command `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` is works. I want to create a self-signed certificate for local IP in my LAN.
I've created a self-signed certificate by command:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -NotBefore (Get-Date) -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(2) -Subject "192.168.1.100" -KeyAlgorithm "RSA" -KeyLength 2048 -HashAlgorithm "SHA256" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" -KeyUsage KeyEncipherment -FriendlyName "HTTPS development certificate" -TextExtension @("2.5.29.19={critical}{text}","2.5.29.37={critical}{text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1","2.5.29.17={critical}{text}DNS=192.168.1.100")
```

Then I copied certificate in trusted folder in certificates store:

[image]

After this I edited appsettings.Development.json:

```
"Kestrel": {
"Endpoints": {
  "localhostHttp": {
    "Url": "http://192.168.1.100:5000"
  },
  "localhostHttps": {
    "Url": "https://192.168.1.100:5001",
    "Certificate": {
      "Subject": "192.168.1.100",
      "Store": "Root",
      "Location": "CurrentUser",
      "AllowInvalid": true
    }
  }
}
```

But no result:

[image]

Is possible to create certificate like this?

Comment: The DotNet documentation contains an example for a localhost IP: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps#example-9